# Is it possible to turn a core patch into a module for AzerothCore?

Tags: azerothcore

Lets say I have to patch few files of the core, example:

```
src/server/game/Handlers/MiscHandler.cpp

+code line 1
+code line 2
+code line 3
```

```
src/server/game/Handlers/ChatHandler.cpp

+code line 1
+code line 2
+code line 3
```

Can I implement these patches into a module? If it's possible, could you please post an example, how can be done, so I can get the idea?

Thank you!

Just to mention that I've already seen the module skeleton repo, I can see that there is a src/ folder with two files - loader.h and Player.cpp, but other than than, not sure how proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. When writing a module you use the existing hooks that are available in AzerothCore. If you need a hook that is not existing yet, you can simply create it and [send a PR to AzerothCore](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/How-to-create-a-PR).

### How to add new hooks: a practical example

I needed to create a very simple module that sends the player a warning whenever he/she leaves the BG queue after being invited to join.

This is the code of my module, very basic:

```cpp
void OnBattlegroundDesertion(Player* player, const BattlegroundDesertionType type) override
{
    if (sConfigMgr->GetBoolDefault(DESERTION_ENABLED_CONFIG, false))
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case BG_DESERTION_TYPE_LEAVE_QUEUE:
            case BG_DESERTION_TYPE_NO_ENTER_BUTTON:
                ChatHandler(player->GetSession()).PSendSysMessage("%s", sConfigMgr->GetStringDefault(WARNING_TEXT_CONFIG, "").c_str());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

the full source code of the module is available here: https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-desertion-warnings

Looks very easy right? Especially if you had that `OnBattlegroundDesertion` method that gave me what I needed (the `Player` and the `BattlegroundDesertionType`).

There was only one problem... the hook `OnBattlegroundDesertion` didn't exist before!

But it's ok, I just had to implement it in the core, and this is the PR that does the job:

https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/4619

As you can see it's just a matter of creating the method in `ScriptMgr.h` and `ScriptMgr.cpp` (the same way other hook-methods are created) and then call it around the core whenever I needed it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. 

So I guess, in order to add a code, first I need to know if that code is related to a existing Hook. 

Is there an easy way of telling if certain code belongs to a hook?

Comment: not really, it depends on the specific use case. You can try to look for it either in the list of hooks (`ScriptMgr.h`) or in those parts of the core where you want to apply your patch

Comment: Thank you for your time!