# Error during compiling: `identifier not found` (code C3861)

Tags: azerothcore

I have a field in my `acore_characters` table named 'rank' with a tinyint which ranges from 0 to 3 inclusive, based on player's progression. I need to read that value at both login and at certain specific circumstances.
I wrote the following `PreparedStatement`: `"SELECT rank FROM acore_characters WHERE guid = ?"` and then the code which is supposed to read that value:

```
uint16 GetCharactersRank(uint64 guid) {

PreparedStatement* stmt = CharacterDatabase.GetPreparedStatement(mystatement);
stmt->setUInt32(0, GetGUID());
PreparedQueryResult result = CharacterDatabase.Query(stmt);
if (result) {
    [...truncated]
```

and then fetching the result and so on, but then I get a code C8361 when compiling because `'GetGUID':identifier not found` in Player.cpp file...what goes wrong? The other `GetGUID` calls throughout the file dont give this result. I'm not very fond of c++, any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to directly patch the core to add customisations to it. Instead, use **modules**.

An example can be found here: [Is it possible to turn a core patch into a module for AzerothCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340549/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-core-patch-into-a-module-for-azerothcore)

You can have a look and copy the [skeleton-module](https://github.com/azerothcore/skeleton-module) and start modifying it to create your own.

In your case, you probably want to use the `OnLogin` player hook.